# can't connect to remote mysql 5.6 server from local mysql 8.0 client. SSL protocol not supported

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

Here's my error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

I recently began playing with Ubuntu 20.04 and everytime I try to log into a remote 5.6 server, I get that error message.  It doesn't matter if the user requires SSL or not.  I still get it.  I tried setting MinProtocol to None in openssl.cnf, but I couldn't find a lot of recent information.

The same giddyup works on MacOS and Ubuntu 18.04.  Just not 20.04.  Is MySQL client 8.0 not backwards compatible to MySQL server 5.6?

MySQL 8.0 client is one hint.
Also Ubuntu 20.04 has deprecated TLS 1.0
if you *Server* is only supporting (like an old RDS instance), you might need to update that, and nothing to do client side.

Answer:

Client is correct, this is a Server Fault.
the deprecation enforced by the SSL library in 20.04 was expected.

Server must be updated.

see for details if you are using RDS

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604170/can-no-longer-connect-to-rds-mysql-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-rails

Comment: I had the same problem today and I just solved it. Below what I did:

- Upgrade the MySQL engine to 5.6.46
- Change the root connection passwords (I removed special characters, because I read on a forum that could be related)
- Updated SSL / TLS certificates

Comment: posted a similar question on stackoverflow, with some more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604170/can-no-longer-connect-to-rds-mysql-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-rails I can confirm the MySQL 8 client is not a problem since it was working with ubuntu 19.10. sounds like upgrading the minor version on RDS is what I am gonna try.